# Android - How to get CLEARKEY_UUID from MediaDrm

Tags: uniqueidentifier, unique-id, widevine

Is there any way to extract CLEARKEY_UUID (unique id) from MediaDrm, like we are doing it for WIDEVINE_UUID. I can share the sample code in which we are getting WIDEVINE_UUID, so someone may get idea that what I am asking for.

```
UUID wideVineUuid = new UUID(-0x121074568629b532L, -0x5c37d8232ae2de13L);
MediaDrm mediaDrm = new MediaDrm(wideVineUuid);` 
byte[] wideVineId = new byte[0];
wideVineId = mediaDrm.getPropertyByteArray(MediaDrm.PROPERTY_DEVICE_UNIQUE_ID);
android.util.Base64.encodeToString(wideVineId, Base64.NO_WRAP);
```

Answer (score 1):

As described at https://dashif.org/identifiers/content_protection/, the Clearkey UUID is `e2719d58-a985-b3c9-781a-b030af78d30e`, so you would need to use `UUID(-0x1d8e62a7567a4c37L, 0x781AB030AF78D30EL)` when you create the `MediaDrm` in order to to access the `MediaDrm.PROPERTY_DEVICE_UNIQUE_ID` property.

Note there is also the W3C Common PSSH UUID which was used back in the day, which is `1077efec-c0b2-4d02-ace3-3c1e52e2fb4b` (`UUID(0x1077EFECC0B24D02L, 0xACE33C1E52E2FB4BL)`), but you almost certainly want the first one.

Comment: No, I want code snippet (if any) to get the ClearKey or Common PSSH UUIDs.

Comment: I assume you mean `MediaDrm.PROPERTY_DEVICE_UNIQUE_ID`. In which case, you simply use exactly the same code you provided, but replace the UUID in the first line with one of the UUIDs in the answer. If that's not what you meant, you need to be much clearer about what _exactly_ you need.

Comment: It was the first thing that I did, replaced UUID in the same code, but there was a null exception.

So I am thinking that above code is only to get UUID for WideVine, and that there is some other way to get Common PSSH unique id.

Comment: Its 'java.lang.IllegalArgumentException', not null exception.

Comment: That exception is thrown when the underlying DRM system does not support the requested property. So presumably the clearkey CDM doesn't provision a unique identifier (which makes sense given clearkey is not DRM and would have no need for this identifier).